# Error : mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops

Following is the code. Verified indentation. Unable to figure out the exact issue.

Code :

```
 - name: Create K8s ingress
     k8s:
      api_version: networking.k8s.io/v1
      namespace: "{{namespace}}"
      definition:
        kind: Ingress
        metadata:
          name: "{{namespace}}-ingress"
          annotations:
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'false'
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/hsts: 'false'
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: core-service
             nginx.org/websocket-services: core-service
        spec:
          rules:
          - host: "{MY_DOMAIN}}"
            http:
              paths:
                - backend:
                   service:
                     name: "wordpress"
                     port:
                       number: 80
                  path: /
                  pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

**Error :**
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/mnt/disc2/workspace/wp-sr-demo/auth-playbooks/wordpress/roles/deploy/tasks/main.yml': line 110, column 51, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
                                              ^ here
```

This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote. For instance:

```
when: "ok" in result.stdout
```

Could be written as:

when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

when: "'ok' in result.stdout"

Comment: yaml doesnt like sign minus in key....either you have to set the key between quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation of the attributes *name* and *k8s* is wrong

```yaml
 - name: Create K8s ingress
     k8s:
```

The correct indentation of the attributes *name* and *k8s* must be the same because they belong to the same dictionary

```yaml
   - name: Create K8s ingress
     k8s:
```

If you move the first line two spaces to the right you'll get [valid YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/).

Comment: the indentation of K8 & name is good in my file. Maybe bcoz I copied here wrong. The issue seems to be with the annotations part. Do I need to use double quotes or single quotes for annotations? Copying valid YAML code and will give it a try.

Comment: You can use both [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style) and [7.3.1. Double-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#731-double-quoted-style). Try the single-quoted style. In the single-quoted style, only ``'`` has to be escaped. Fix the YAML to avoid confusion.

Comment: Worked with Single quotes. Thank you Vladimir